# how to write to database after javascript client side photo resize and upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, upload

I have found a script online which resizes an image client side and then uploads the image to server. This works fine but what I need is to write the image name to mysql database. I know how to do it, but its not working and I think it has something to do with the fact that the script runs client side.

Can anyone look at the following and see where to put the mysql statement. Or if there is a better way of doing it altogether.

upload-form.php

```
<script>
function uploadphoto()
{
    if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob)
    {
        var files = document.getElementById('filesToUpload').files;      
        for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) 
        {
            resizeAndUpload(files[i]);
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
    }
}

function resizeAndUpload(file)
{
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function() 
    {
        var tempImg = new Image();
        tempImg.src = reader.result;
        tempImg.onload = function()
        {
            var MAX_WIDTH = 695;
            var MAX_HEIGHT = 470;
            var tempW = tempImg.width;
            var tempH = tempImg.height;

            if (tempW > tempH) 
            {
                if (tempW > MAX_WIDTH)
                {
                    tempH *= MAX_WIDTH / tempW;
                    tempW = MAX_WIDTH;
                }
            } 
            else
            {
                if (tempH > MAX_HEIGHT)
                {
                    tempW *= MAX_HEIGHT / tempH;
                    tempH = MAX_HEIGHT;
                }
            }

            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvas.width = tempW;
            canvas.height = tempH;
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, tempW, tempH);
            var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function(ev)
            {
                document.getElementById('filesInfo').innerHTML = 'Done!';
            };
            xhr.open('POST', 'upload-resized-photo.php', true);

            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            var data = 'image=' + dataURL;
            xhr.send(data);
        }
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
</script>



<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" onsubmit="uploadphoto()">
    <div class="row">
      <label for="fileToUpload">Select Files to Upload</label><br />
      <input type="file" name="filesToUpload[]" id="filesToUpload" multiple="multiple" />
      <output id="filesInfo"></output>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </div>
</form>
```

upload-resized-photo.php

```
<?php
    if ($_POST) 
    {
        define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'uploads/');
        $img = $_POST['image'];
        $img = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $img);
        $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
        $data = base64_decode($img);
        $file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.jpg';
        $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);

        // I did have the mysql insert here but it didnt even execute. Think it is due to xhr.open post method.
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I test the following code on my computer:

```
if ($_POST) 
{
    define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'uploads/');
    $img = $_POST['image'];
    $img = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $img);
    $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
    $data = base64_decode($img);
    $file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.jpg';
    $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "test";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "INSERT INTO images (image_name)
    VALUES ('{$file}')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();        
}
```

check your folder permissions, see the following images (Mysql + Files)

[image][image]

Comment: The file does upload correctly to server but I can't get an sql statement to execute from upload - resized - photo.

Comment: Yeah that was it. Working 100% now. Do you know how I could prevent any files other than images to be uploaded. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

This function check all input[type=file]

```
var _validFileExtensions = [".jpg", ".jpeg", ".bmp", ".gif", ".png"];    
function Validate(oForm) {
var arrInputs = oForm.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0; i < arrInputs.length; i++) {
    var oInput = arrInputs[i];
    if (oInput.type == "file") {
        var sFileName = oInput.value;
        if (sFileName.length > 0) {
            var blnValid = false;
            for (var j = 0; j < _validFileExtensions.length; j++) {
                var sCurExtension = _validFileExtensions[j];
                if (sFileName.substr(sFileName.length - sCurExtension.length, sCurExtension.length).toLowerCase() == sCurExtension.toLowerCase()) {
                    blnValid = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!blnValid) {
                alert("Sorry, " + sFileName + " is invalid, allowed extensions are: " + _validFileExtensions.join(", "));
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}

return true;
}
```

you should call that function in:

```
function uploadphoto(oForm)
{
if(!Validate(oForm)){
    return false;
}
if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob)
{
    var files = document.getElementById('filesToUpload').files;      
    for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) 
    {
        resizeAndUpload(files[i]);
    }
}
else 
{
    alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
}
return false;
 }
```

and in your form pass the form as parameter:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" onsubmit="return uploadphoto(this)">
```

Good luck

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for  Appreciate the help.